# Evaluating a 2-variable limit

Tags: limits

Could you help me evaluating this limit?

> $$
> \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left[\arccos\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-
> 2x\cdot \cos(y)+1}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)-y\right]
> $$

Comment: L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: @ Doctor Dan I'm not sure of it, but does the form $\arccos(+\infty-\infty)$ allow the application of De L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: @BinaryBurst, could you please confirm the question is not modified by the edit?

Comment: I strongly suspect that using Taylor polynomials is easier here. Start from the inside, using $(1+u)^{-1/2}=1-u/2+3u^2/4+O(u^3)$ with $u=x^2+2x\cos y$ and work your way outwards.

Comment: It is the same question :) And thank you for the nice editing.

Comment: @BinaryBurst, how can we call this as $2-$ variable limit unless there is a limit for $y$ like http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091102014802AAn1Pub and http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091128044316AAoJkNp

Comment: Oh, no,no ... Y is an arbitrary constant. This limit is only for x. I suspect, though, that the limit might not exist for every value of y.

Comment: Try y=pi/2 and x tending to 0 then  the limit is 1/2.

Comment: Let's assume y is from 0 to pi/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Notice:** I changed what I think a typo  otherwise the limit is undefined.

By the Taylor series we have (and we denote $a=\cos(y)$)
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-2xa+1}}=1+xa+x^2(\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{1}{2})+O(x^3)$$
so
$$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-2xa+1}}-\frac{1}{x}=a+x(\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{1}{2})+O(x^2)$$
Now using
$$\arccos(a+\alpha x)=\arccos(a)-\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}x+O(x^2)$$
we have
$$\arccos(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-2xa+1}}-\frac{1}{x})=\arccos(a)-\frac{\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}x+O(x^2)$$
so if we suppose that $y\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left[\arccos\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-2x\cdot \cos(y)+1}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)-y\right]=-\frac{\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$

Comment: I am officially impressed :)

Comment: Actually, this is fairly standard once you have mastered Tayoler series and big-O notation. But +1 anyhow, for actually doing it. It is fairly laborious, if standard. One nitpick, though: The result is false for $y<0$, because for such $y$, $\arccos\cos y\ne y$.

Comment: There is trouble for $y=0$ as well, for then you're taking arccos of a number greater than 1 for $x$ small and positive. The limit from the left might be okay, though – I haven't checked, and have no time right now. But you have to be more careful because of the singularity of arccos at 1.

Comment: I will remember that :D

Comment: ...and limits! ${}{}{}$ ;-)